# A good pythonic way to map bits to characters in python?

Tags: python

`the_map = { 1:'a',0:'b'}`

Now to generate, 8 patterns of `a` and `b` , we create 8 bit patterns:

```
>>> range(8)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
# 001,010,011....111
```

How to map the bits to characters 'a' and 'b' , to receive output like :

```
['aaa','aab','aba'.......'bbb']
```

I am looking for an efficient one liner. My approaches using translate or format seem a bit inefficient to me:

```
>>> import string
>>> [bin(x)[2:].zfill(3).translate(string.maketrans('01','ab')) for x in xrange(8)]
['aaa', 'aab', 'aba', 'abb', 'baa', 'bab', 'bba', 'bbb']
```

Comment: Is it really so important to have the solution as a one-liner? Is this a realistic requirement? Do you believe shorter code is more efficient?

Comment: I would have say that, once the translation table is build, `translate` should be one of the fastest approach... If you obtain other answers, for educational purpose, could you provide some benchmark?

Comment: @SylvainLeroux, Yes my intent is to learn other approaches for educational purpose, I think there could be raw approaches using bitwise operators or basic strings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`product`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> [''.join(i) for i in product('ABC',repeat=3)]
['AAA', 'AAB', 'AAC', 'ABA', 'ABB', 'ABC', 'ACA', 'ACB', 'ACC', 'BAA', 'BAB', 'B
AC', 'BBA', 'BBB', 'BBC', 'BCA', 'BCB', 'BCC', 'CAA', 'CAB', 'CAC', 'CBA', 'CBB'
, 'CBC', 'CCA', 'CCB', 'CCC']
```

Answer (score 2):

Not a huge improvement besides readability, but I think new style formatting could be a better fit here:

```
>>> '{:0<3b}'.format(1).translate(string.maketrans('01', 'ab'))
'baa'
```

Answer (score 0):

One-liner using `map`. Certainly *not* a performance improvement, I guess:

```
>>> the_list = (0,1,16,255,32768)
>>> the_map = { '1':'a','0':'b'}
>>> list(''.join(map(the_map.get, (bit for bit in bin(num)[2:].zfill(3)))) for num in the_list)
['bbb', 'bba', 'abbbb', 'aaaaaaaa', 'abbbbbbbbbbbbbbb']
```

I fill at 3 digits as in your example. Please note you question map '1' to 'a' and '0' to 'b' whereas your example does the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

As it is question of creativity ;) I post an other answer -- totally different approach.

Since we are working with 8-bit patterns:

```
# Build our own translation table for all the 8-bit values (unsigned)
>>> import string
>>> ttable = string.maketrans('01','ab')
>>> the_map = {}
>>> for i in range(256):
...     the_map[i] = bin(i)[2:].zfill(3).translate(ttable)
... 

# Do the actual translation of an arbitrary list
>>> the_list = (0,1,16,255)
>>> map(the_map.get, the_list)
['aaa', 'aab', 'baaaa', 'bbbbbbbb']
```